# Chrome Local host page stands still there after even closing localserver

Tags: google-chrome, webserver, apportable

i started [a mini server](https://www.aidex.de/software/webserver/)  and terminated. next time started it does not allow port 80. but chrome make it functioning as localhost: when a server starts at port 81. But when i terminated next local server the Localhost page stands there still with all frames. is it chrome bug?

if not how i can terminate that port 80 host page not functioning as server but keep listing as starting from that predefined root whenever i write localhost: ..?

I have try to change local root with same aplication but since local is defined beforehand.
i am forced to use localhost:81 or localhost:8080 to reach new root.
it keeps localhost at port:80 at predefined root.

Answer (score 0):

The web servers are still running, even if you disconnected from them most likely.

If you're on Windows, open your Task Manager, find the mini server instances and "End" them.

If you're not on Windows, in the terminal you can run `ps`, which lists the running processes and get the PID numbers. Then you can run `kill -9 <PID number>` to terminate them.

In the future you might want to check the mini server documentation on how to terminate the server once you don't need it.

Background: Server applications often "daemonize", meaning that even though you cancel them in the terminal, they keep running. This is not a web browser issue, it's expected behavior when you run server processes.

Comment: that's true. restarted system. now i can use port 80 again. i guess that api has a secret service or stack in memory that can not be seen at taskbar easily.